# How can I replace Context Api and redux in wix/react-native-navigation

Tags: wix

We use wix/react-native-navigation and tried to use Context API from react.We need all the screenshots to receive data and when changing in one place, there is a change in all places.The api context is not suitable, it makes a context for each screen, that is, when changed in 1 screen, the data will not be rerender in another. I would also not like to use Redux since editors are not signed in all screenshots, and it’s too difficult to forward props.
Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a case for the [model view controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.

Each screen would be a `view` in this pattern. You need to trigger a rerender when the data changes. You can define functions in the react context (`model`) and then reference it in your lifecycle methods (`controller`) of your different views.